# How an Azure Functions app can be copied?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions app working for development purposes, using a Table Storage account with test data. Now I want to have a separate environment (same Functions app with different storage config/conn-string) for production.

So, how can I "copy" my Azure Functions App in order to avoid manual recreation of it in the Azure portal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can move the content from one Function App to another. The simplest is to copy the contents of your `wwwroot` folder to the other environment, which you can do by [using Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service), [FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deploy-ftp), etc.

Another way that is often simpler and less error prone is to setup CI/CD so that different branches will trigger deployments to different environments. You can learn more about the continuous deployment options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-continuous-deployment).

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. Any tips on how I can (in an automated or scripted way) copy an entire Azure Function App resource, maybe even the entire resource group that contains Application Insights and a Storage Account?

Answer (score 2):

1. Stop Azure Function
2. Open up the browser, navigate to `https://{functionName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`
3. Navigate to site/wwwroot
4. Create a new folder (which would represent your new functions) and copy the contents of your function app (which is one of the folder in this directory) into that folder. Folder names = Function Names
5. Start Azure Function

Comment: I was talking about the whole Function App, which is composed of several small functions (those you're talking about). Thanks for the try.

Comment: As I always end up here when I'm doing this, the command to clone the function is `robocopy dir1 dir2 /E`

Comment: Also, I don't see why you should have to 'stop' the function. After all, it isn't going to change while you're cloning it...

Answer (score 0):

By using the Azure Functions CLI, you can just copy a directory, then publish using `func azure functionapp publish`

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/123779/azure-clone-a-function.html